# How do I counter opponents' EX Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-tcg-online

I recently started playing pokemon tcgo but I know how all mechanism works and  have a good deck. Problem starts when I enter in tournaments which requires 8 tickets and it takes a lot time to get more tickets.

While in tournaments every opponent seems to have EX- cards and my team only consist of some basic Pokemons and their 2 stage evolutions also 1 Kyrem EX but as game starts building their EX Pokémon starts to overwhelm my pokemons and ultimately defeat me , leading me to the 7-8th place . Is there any way to counter those EX-pokemons? Any good strategy?

I play in Expanded deck format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played in a while, so my answer is going to be focused on the Plasma expansions, which although not particularly recent, are still part of Expanded. They are several cards made to help deal with EX-Pokemon.

**Cards that are immune to EX-Pokemon**

Various versions of [Sigilyph](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sigilyph_(Dragons_Exalted_52)) and [Suicune](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Suicune_(Plasma_Blast_20)) in the Plasma expansions have Safeguard.

> Prevent all effects of attacks, including damage, done to this Pokémon by Pokémon-EX.

[image] [image]

**Cards to Shut Down EX-Pokemon**

Plasma Freeze [Jolteon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Jolteon_(Plasma_Freeze_34))  due to Electro-Defuse

> If the Defending Pokémon is a Pokémon-EX, that Pokémon can't attack during your opponent's next turn.

And using the Furious Fists [Eevee](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eevee_(Furious_Fists_80)) to search for it and evolve by attaching energy

[image] [image]

**Cards to help damage EX-Pokemon**

[Silver Bangle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Silver_Bangle_(Plasma_Blast_88)) boosts damage against EX-Pokemon

> The attacks of the Pokémon this card is attached to (excluding Pokémon-EX) do 30 more damage to Active Pokémon-EX (before applying Weakness and Resistance).

[image]

Comment: Oh so I need to trade to get this cards right? Anyway to add I found some cards which would fit in my deck such as Regice and Carbink card with safeguard ability